# Is there a way have a centered div background color "bleed" to viewport edge without tables?

Tags: html, css

This is for a standard centered responsive .content div with various breakpoints to set its width.

The design requirements is part of the right side of .content has a div with a colored background - black in this case - and that background color "bleeds" all the way to the right edge of the viewport. Likewise, it could be used on the left side also.

What I came up with involves tables, but I was wondering if there was a non-table version I wasn't able to figure out.

```
<div id="contain">
    <div id="left"><!-- nothing can go here to spacing breaks --></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="rightfloat">status</div>
        <div id="somecontent">content<br>blue borders for dev only</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right"><!-- nothing can go here to spacing breaks --></div>
</div>

#contain {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
}

#left, #right {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

#left {
    background: white;
}

#right {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

#content {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 360px;
    background: #F00;
    height: 4em;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
}

#rightfloat {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I've created a js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/toddzebert/5DWFh/

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a diagram of your expected output?

Comment: You mean like [**this**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/joBpE)?

Comment: That helps, I assume that is what you have right now. So based on that, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @jtorrescr I figured the jsfiddle was sufficient.

Comment: @Paulie_D That seems to work, thanks. I never thought to use :after with "some huge width" figuring that would force the page width really huge.